# Перехват завершения процесса

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Существует некая функция, структура которой:

```
    {
    int i;
    thread(){ 
     //тут меняю значение i
     ...
    };
    return i;
    }
```

Мне необходимо перехватить каким-то образом завершение работы `thread`, потому что на входе у меня `i=1`, на выходе тоже, получается, так как выполнение идет параллельно.

Comment: `thread.join()` - будет ожидать завершения треда

Comment: Супер, спасибо. А если это все организовано не через 'thread', а через стороннюю функцию, через 'new'? Join будет работать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы стартуете новый поток и идете дальше, не дожидаясь результата (изменения i) поэтому отдаете все тот же i = 1.

[Во дока по тредам.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Есть команда join() - которая ждет пока тред умрет и потом идет дальше.

Comment: Супер, вот, наверное, то, что и требовалось)